# how to read a file into a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to read a serial of three digits, corresponding to row, column and value,  from a text file into a 2D array.

1st digit = row

2nd digit = column

3rd digit = value

Here's what's in the file:

```
014 023 037 040 050 069 070 088 100 110 125 130 143 150 160 170 180 200 211 220 230 240 250 263 270 280 306 310 320 330 342 357 360 370 380 404 410 427 430 440 450 461 470 483 500 510 520 535 544 550 560 570 589 600 610 622 630 640 650 661 670 683 700 710 720 730 745 750 764 770 780 805 810 824 830 840 851 862 876 880
```

For learning purpose, I was able to create code that would work if the text file was in this format (similar to what the final array would look like)

```
0 4 3 7 0 0 9 0 8
0 0 5 0 3 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
6 0 0 0 2 7 0 0 0
4 0 7 0 0 0 1 0 3
0 0 0 5 4 0 0 0 9
0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 3
0 0 0 0 5 0 4 0 0
5 0 4 0 0 1 2 6 0
```

but can't figure how to make it work with the 3 digits:

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public final int[][] chargerJeu(String nomFichier){
    try {   
        File unfichier = new File (nomFichier);
        BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(unfichier));
        String ligne;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while ((ligne = entree.readLine()) != null)  //file reading
        {
            String[] values = ligne.split(" ");
            for (String str : values)
            {
                int z = Integer.parseInt(str);
                grille[x][y]=z;
                y=y+1;
            }
            x=x+1;
            y=0;
        }
        entree.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println ("Erreur, fichier inexistant!");
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println ("Erreur d'ecriture : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return grille;
}
```

Would anyone know how I could adapt my code to read the three digits in my text file?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is `grille` defined?

Comment: It is defined as a class attribute (I didn't want to include all the code thinking it would be overkill).

Comment: All the code would be overkill, but including relevant code is critical. Leaving your readers guess how and when variables are defined and initialized makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all information apparently is in one line, and always the same (three digits), you could do something like this:

```
for (String str : values) {
  char[] c = str.toCharArray();
  int x = Character.getNumericValue(c[0]);
  int y = Character.getNumericValue(c[1]);
  int z = Character.getNumericValue(c[2]);
  grille[x][y] = z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `str`contains the four digits:

```
x = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0,1));
y = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1,2));
z = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2,3));
```

Not super performant but easy to understand.

And to make sure `str` has no leading or trailing whitespece, do this in advance:

```
str = str.trim();
```

I also recommend some error checking: The string could have more or less than three digits. It could also contain non-digit characters.

Comment: z = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2,str.lenght)); would be more true

Comment: What if x or y are double digit numbers?

Comment: @Arman with the data in the format "014 023 037 040.." there would be no way of knowing that.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I feel like a general solution would still be better here (one that works with more digits). Good point though.

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya: Why?

Comment: @Arman: Sure, but then the OP would have to change the input file format.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Would he? I don't understand why the current file format wouldn't work.

Comment: @FrankPuffer if input be 7815 it means x = 7 y = 8 and value is 15 with your solution value would be 1 and with others pointed out x and y values gonne be double digit some time

Comment: @AlperFıratKaya: How do you know? It could also mean `x=78, y=1, z=5`  or `x=7, y=81, z=5`.

Comment: @FrankPuffer its true input contains so much ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Before defining `int z = Integer.parseInt(str)` we must first separate the `value` from `str`

Step 1: Get the length of x, and y as Strings:

```
int xLen = Integer.toString(x).length();
int yLen = Integer.toString(y).length();
```

So now we know that `str.substring((xLen-1)+(yLen-1), str.length())` will be the value you are looking for. So `z = Integer.parseInt(str.substring((xLen-1)+(yLen-1), str.length()));`This solution is meant to work for arrays that may have "double digit" indexes. So if `x > 9 || y > 9` this will still work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this after you convert the string to an int:

```
    x = z / 100;
    z -= 100 * x;
    y = z / 10;
    z -= y * 10;
```

You should be able to keep your code as is, just don't increment x and y in your loops.